# Data pre processing Libraries

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm new to Deep Learning. I only know about scikit learn when I have to pre process data for a neural network. are there any other good libraries for that ?

Comment: Hello Noob Coder, 

It would be better for you to elaborate on the problem you are trying to solve and what sort of pre-processing you are looking for in order to get better answers.

Comment: I only need to Pre Process data ( one hot encoding , remove variable trap , fill missing values , standard scale) Currently I use sklearn library . I wonder is their any other libraries or soft wares people using

Answer (score 1):

**Pre-processing** is *50%* of the entire pipeline. With better data you build better machine learning/deep learning models. But unfortunately, cleaning data is something that needs time and experience. You need to visualise it and make your hands dirty. The aim is to remove noise, garbage and outliers, in short.

There are some really good data visualisation libraries in Python such as :

- [MatplotLib](https://matplotlib.org)
- [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org)
- GGPlot
- Bokeh
- PyGal
- Plotly
- and [more](https://mode.com/blog/python-data-visualization-libraries).

Since, you are comfortable with Scikit learn, as you mentioned in the question, I would suggest you to look up the [preprocessing](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) modules in scikit learn, it contains several APIs such as feature extraction, normalization, feature scaling, mean removal, variance scaling, standardization, etc.

> But, it is always better to understand the data, visualise it like a
>   [story](https://www.storytellingwithdata.com/) and clean it manually,
>   slowly, instead of passing it through predefined frameworks or
>   pipelines.

These videos :

- [Why You Need Data-Preprocessing](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/data-genes-medicine/importance-of-data-preprocessing-0Qo23)
- [Data-preprocessing tasks](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/data-genes-medicine/data-preprocessing-tasks-Zdg0l)

can be helpful. There are many more available easily. Good luck !

Also, do upvote my answer, if it has helped you. It encourages the community to help each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a bunch of pretrained models using pytorch

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html

There's a great course in Udacity related to https://www.udacity.com/course/deep-learning-pytorch--ud188

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you could use various libraries that support a bunch of pre-processing like handling missing values. Over the top of head, pandas is a really good library to do the needful. It supports handling missing values, encoding and lot of other cool features.